# Windows Batch: Automatically upload local CSV file list via FTP

Tags: file-upload, csv, ftp, batch-file, automation

I built a script that reads a CSV file for a list of files and then uploads them to an FTP server. The CSV structure is like this:

`local_file,remote_file`

The script creates a text file with all the necessary FTP commands and then runs the FTP command. Everything works, except that the for loop executes code that is outside of it's command, i.e., everything below `echo put "%1" "%2" >> %Commands%` is also executed on every for loop, and instead of getting a nicely formatted file with all the put commands I get this (from the commands file output):

```
open servername 
username 
password 
binary 
put "local_path_to\first_file_on_the_list.php" "remote_path_to\first_file_on_the_list.php" 
close 
bye   
put "-d" "-i" 
close 
bye   
put "-d" "-i" 
close 
bye   
put "-d" "-i" 
close
...
```

Here is the script code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions

rem Connection credentials
set Server=servername
set UserName=username
set Password=password

set Commands="commands.txt"
echo open %Server% > %Commands%
echo %UserName% >> %Commands%
echo %Password% >> %Commands%
echo binary >> %Commands%

rem Read the CSV file line by line
for /f %%a in (matches3.csv) do call :parse %%a

rem Transform CSV line into FTP put commmand
:parse
echo put "%1" "%2" >> %Commands%

:end
rem Add commands to close ftp conn
echo close >> %Commands%
echo bye   >> %Commands%

rem Perform the FTP upload
echo loggin in to ftp...
FTP -d -i -s:%Commands% %Server%
echo finished.
pause

rem Clean up.
if exist %Commands% del %Commands%
endlocal
exit
```

I don't understand why everything below :end is getting executed!
Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why shouldn't the code below `:end` execute? You never put anything in the script to end the :parse routine.

The first ewall answer should almost work, except you need a GOTO :END after the FOR statement. I don't see how a proper implementation of his suggestion can lead to an endless loop.

Another option is to simply move your subroutine after your EXIT statement.

You have other hidden problems. File paths/names can contain spaces, so the default FOR delimiter of space,tab will not preserve the entire line if there are spaces. The default EOL will also cause any line that begins with `;` to be ignored. That is a potential (but unlikely) problem, because a valid filename can begin with `;`.

The solution is to set EOL to a character that cannot begin a valid file spec, and set DELIMS to nothing: `"EOL=: DELIMS="`

It is much more efficient to enclose all your file writing lines within parentheses and redirect the output just once. It's also easier to write and looks better.

***Edit -*** *The original script was attempting to connect to the server in both the ftp script and the ftp command line. One or the other had to be removed. I removed it from the ftp script.*

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions

rem Connection credentials
set Server=servername
set UserName=username
set Password=password

set Commands="commands.txt"
(
  echo %UserName%
  echo %Password%
  echo binary

  rem Read the CSV file line by line
  for /f "eol=: delims=" %%a in (matches3.csv) do call :parse %%a

  rem Add commands to close ftp conn
  echo close
  echo bye
)>%Commands%

rem Perform the FTP upload
echo logging in to ftp...
FTP -d -i -s:%Commands% %Server%
echo finished.
pause

rem Clean up.
if exist %Commands% del %Commands%
endlocal
exit

rem Transform CSV line into FTP put commmand
:parse
echo put "%1" "%2"
```

Comment: I like your code, however it takes my to an endless loop on the logging in to ftp... stage

Comment: @pilau - There is no endless loop in the batch script itself. The problem must be with the ftp session, though I don't see anything wrong with the ftp script that is generated. I'm not an ftp expert, so I don't have much advice to give. Try using ftp interactively and discover what combination of commands allow you to login, upload a single file, and exit. Enter those commands into a ftp script file using a text editor and confirm your script works with ftp. Then modify your batch file accordingly to generate the correct sequence of commands.

Comment: I will do that and get back to you with the results. Thanks!

Comment: Here are the results: So I let the script write out the commands file. Then, from cmd, I fired: "ftp -s:commands.txt" and everything was uploaded successfully.

I don't know what is causing the endless loop in this script :(

Comment: @pilau - Try using the command that worked inside your batch script. In your current batch script you specify the host server in the command line, then you try to open a connection to the server within the ftp script. That doesn't look right.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that this morning, but I thought since you didn't change it in your script it's OK. Silly me. I removed it, and it works!

Comment: Will you be so kind to update your script with this modification?

Comment: @pilau - fix has been made to my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The `:end` doesn't stop the [`CALL` function](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html) from running, it's just a label. Instead, I suspect you meant to use `GOTO :eof`, which would return to the for-loop:

```
...
rem Read the CSV file line by line
for /f %%a in (matches3.csv) do call :parse %%a

rem Transform CSV line into FTP put commmand
:parse
echo put "%1" "%2" >> %Commands%

goto :eof

rem Add commands to close ftp conn
...
```

Or, rather than using a call, you may find it a lot simpler to use parenthesis, like this:

```
...
rem Read the CSV file line by line
for /f %%a in (matches3.csv) do (
  rem Transform CSV line into FTP put command
  echo put "%%a" "%%b" >> %Commands%
)

rem Add commands to close ftp conn
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the super quick reply. The first solution doesn't work at all - it leads to an endless loop. The second solution makes everything work, except instead for outputting this: `put "local_path_to\first_file_on_the_list.php" "remote_path_to\first_file_on_the_list.php"` it outputs this: `put "local_path_to\first_file_on_the_list.php,remote_path_to\first_file_on_the_list.php" "%b"`. What do you think?

Comment: In your 2nd option, you forgot to use "TOKENS=1,2 DELIMS=,". But there is a problem with your design. Commas are valid in file and folder names, so the FOR statement will not properly parse names with commas. Your 1st option is still missing a GOTO :END after the FOR statement

Answer (score 0):

maybe this works

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions

rem Connection credentials
set Server=servername
set UserName=username
set Password=password

set Commands="commands.txt"
echo open %Server% > %Commands%
echo %UserName% >> %Commands%
echo %Password% >> %Commands%
echo binary >> %Commands%

rem Read the CSV file line by line
for /f %%a in (matches3.csv) do call :parse %%a

rem Transform CSV line into FTP put commmand
:parse
echo put "%1" "%2" >> %Commands%

:end
rem Add commands to close ftp conn
echo close >> %Commands%
echo bye   >> %Commands%

rem Perform the FTP upload
echo loggin in to ftp...
FTP -d -i -s:%Commands% %Server%
echo finished.
pause

rem Clean up.
if exist %Commands% del %Commands%
endlocal
exit /b



rem Transform CSV line into FTP put commmand
:parse
echo put "%1" "%2" >> %Commands%
exit /b

:end
rem Add commands to close ftp conn
echo close >> %Commands%
echo bye   >> %Commands%
exit /b
```